# summing multiple sets

Tags: c, algorithm, math

If I have several sets of numbers (just a 2D array where each row is a set):

```
 [ 1, 3, -1, -1]
 [ 2, 4, -1, -1]
 [ 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What would be an algorithm to create a list of sums (ignoring -1's)? the result for the above would be:

```
1+2+7,
1+2+8,
1+2+9,
1+2+10,
1+4+7,
1+4+8,
1+4+9,
1+4+10,
3+2+7,
3+2+8,
3+2+9,
3+2+10,
3+4+7,
3+4+8,
3+4+9,
3+4+10
```

Comment: Remove {-1} from the sets, take the Cartesian product of the new sets, and then add the elements in the results: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: The "algorithm" is already described in the question.  Does it really qualify for the "algorithm" tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each number in the first list, generate all sums starting with that number and all sums recursively generated by applying the same method to all but the first list. When you have no lists left, that is the base case.

Pseudo-code:

```
function find_sums(lists):
    if lists is empty:
        return [""]
    sums = []
    for n in lists[0]:
        if n != -1:
            for sum in find_sums(lists from index 1 onwards):
                sums.append(n + "+" + sum)
    return sums
```

This is called the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).